# Spring. Как сделать alias на другой alias

Tags: java, spring

Допустим есть бин:

```
 <alias name="foo" alias="foo"/>
    <bean id="foo" class="com.foofoo.foo"/>
```

Хочу чтобы вместо него по имени foo вызывался мой бин

пишу так:

```
<alias name="bar" alias="foo"/>
        <bean id="bar" class="com.barbar.bar"/>
```

но падает ошибка expected single matching bean but found 2

как можно реализовать нужное поведение?